# How can I ask this, or will it be too broad?

Tags: discussion

I am a professional software developer. I also play with ESP32, Raspberry PI & the like.

I have an elderly relative, who is too far away for me to visit, and it is also difficult for family who are nearer.

I am thinking of some tele-monitoring.

- I can imagine making a ring-doorbell clime with an 2 and FOSS face recognition Software for $15, so that they don't have to go to the door to see who is there.
- there are FitBit clones, also about $15, which can measure heart rate (sleep, maybe temperature), and also let me know if they are mobile.

In short, I would like to find as many affordably devices as I can to remotely me=monitor a family member's health .... maybe some way of checking that pills are taken, even that he fridge or food cupboard door is opened.

However, most S.E sited have a "closed for being too broad" option. Is there any way to formulate such a Question to be on topic? The problem is that if I knew exactly what devices I wanted, then I could ask a bunch of separate questions, but I really want input for others to tell me what I haven't even considered yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems fine to me. You're asking for hardware that interfaces with a computer that would allow you to remotely monitor a relative. This seems neither too broad or off topic for the site.

Comment: Thanks, but my point is that I will not be naming the piece of hardware, just asking a general "what hardware can I use to monitor health?". Would that still be on topic?

Comment: Yeah, the problem in your scenario is you can't be specific, but you are still asking for purchasable hardware for the problem. You're being as specific as you can in your case so I would consider this still on topic. Usually something that is too broad would have a gigantic answer or not include enough information to give you one.

Comment: Sigh (+1), buy I can't be specific, since this in an exploratory question - what's out there? I guess that it is off-topic, then?

Comment: No, I'm saying I think this is on-topic and a valid question for the site. If I was in the review queues I would not vote to close this as too broad.

Comment: Thanks, then. It's late o'clock over here, but I will buff it up & post it tomorrow a.m (and leave a link here)

Comment: please see (and I hope that you can answer) https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/15128/general-tele-health-monitoring-recommendations)